# Format/parse different Date formats correctly

Tags: javascript, date

I receive `Date` in 3 formats from different `APIs`

1. `UTC` format: `2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` (`String`)
2. `GMT`format: `Thu, 29 Nov 2018 17:30:56 GMT` (`String`)
3. `unixTimeStamp`: `1558606726` (`number`)

Also the `UTC` format sometimes might not have `Z` in the end so the normal parsing will give a time difference.

```
function formatDate(dateString) {
  var dateTime, utcFormatRegex, zeroHourOffsetRegex;

// Some APIs return a Date in standard ISO UTC format may not have Z at the end
  utcFormatRegex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T.*$/;
  zeroHourOffsetRegex = /^.*Z$/;

  if (utcFormatRegex.test(dateString) && !zeroHourOffsetRegex.test(dateString)) {
    dateString+='Z';
  }

    dateTime = new Date(dateString);

}
```

Given that there are parsing functions for all of the different formats,  i need a function that determines which parsing function we should be using based on a `regex` and `parse` it accordingly. If regex is not the ideal solution then how can i approach this?

What I'm getting at is there should probably be a more robust solution than 'if there isn't a Z then add one' to get it to parse through the single date time parser. What if we get another date time format that doesn't play nicely with a Z on the end? We'll be making multiple changes at that point in time.

Comment: why need a regex ?

Comment: I did try it, please don't make that assumption. I asked this question without code to get a general suggestion how to approach this. My function looks somewhat like this, https://codepen.io/kira510/pen/YbJOwe .

Comment: @Liam ^^ The above codepen for your reference.

Comment: *please don't make that assumption* you need to put what you've tried into the question or else, yes, people will make assumptions.

Comment: So what exactly are you stuck on here? You have a regex that checks for the first format, create regexs for the other two and your done?

Comment: A UTC format may have Z or not at the end, and adding a regex check in the middle is not the ideal solution according to me. I guess what I'm getting at is there should probably be a more robust solution than 'if there isn't a Z then add one' to get it to parse through the single date time parser. What if we get another date time format that doesn't play nicely with a Z on the end? We'll be making multiple changes at that point in time.

Comment: Using a regular expression to validate the format is fine, but you need to test strictly, not the loose test you have now. What you're calling "UTC format" is one of the ISO 8601 formats. If the Z is missing it should be treated as local (though not all built–in parsers will).

Comment: just make the Z optional `Z?`

Comment: You know it's impossible to write a regex that will parse **all** date formats right? I still have no idea what your actually asking

Comment: "*We'll be making multiple changes at that point in time.*" indeed. You can't reliably parse a random string, you **must** know the format, and you must tell the parser, or use the right parser for the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression is OK, but you need to test strictly for the formats you're expecting. If you get something you don't expect, throw an error. It's one of the failings of current built–in parsers is that there's no way to specify strict parsing, e.g. where a format is supplied and the parser throws an error if the input string doesn't match.

There are libraries that can help, a search will reveal quite a few.

But if you only have to support the 3 formats in the OP, something like the following may suit:

```js
/* Return a Date where the input may be:
**   string: ISO 8601 timestamp that should be treated as UTC
**           whether it has a trailing Z or not
**   string: Timestamp in the format (using moment.js tokens): 
**           ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss GMT 
**   nunber: UNIX time value, seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC
*/
function toDate(value) {
  // Parse the string & fail early if it fails
  let d = new Date(value);
  
  // Throw error if couldn't parse value
  if (isNaN(d.getTime())) {
    throw 'Invalid timestamp: ' + value;
  }
  
  // Otherwise, do the work
  let days = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat'.split(' ');
  let months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');

  // Test for time value first as that's the easiest
  if (typeof value == 'number' && !isNaN(value)) {
    return new Date(value * 1000);
    
  // Test for ISO 8601 next
  } else if (/^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\dZ?$/.test(value)) {
    return new Date(/Z$/.test(value)? value : value + 'Z');
    
  // Test for random format
  } else if (/^[a-z]{3}, \d?\d [a-z]{3} \d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d GMT$/i.test(value)) {
    let b = value.split(/ |:/);

    if (days.includes(b[0].substr(0,3)) && months.includes(b[2])) {
      let x = new Date(Date.UTC(
                b[3],                 // year
                months.indexOf(b[2]), // month, zero indexed
                b[1],                 // day
                b[4], b[5], b[6]      // hh:mm:ss
              ));
      // Check value was a valid date, only need to check some parts
      if (x.getUTCFullYear() == b[3] &&
          x.getUTCDate() == b[1] &&
          x.getUTCHours() == b[4] &&
          x.getUTCSeconds() == b[6]) {
        return x;
      } else {
        throw 'Invalid timestamp: ' + value;
      }
    }

  // Throw error as must be unknown format
  } else {      
    throw 'Unknown format: ' + value;
  }
}

// Minimal testing 
var isoString0 = '2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    isoString1 = '2014-01-01T00:00:00.000',         // no Z, parse as UTC anyway
    randomString = 'Thu, 29 Nov 2018 17:30:56 GMT',
    unixTimeValue = 1558606726,                     // Assume seconds
    invalidDate0 = '2018-02-29T00:00:00.000Z',      // no 29 Feb in 2018, fail built-in parse
    invalidDate1 = 'Thu, 29 Feb 2018 17:30:56 GMT', // no 29 Feb in 2018, fail manual parse
    invalidFormat = '6/6/2019';                     // Unknown format

[isoString0, isoString1, randomString, unixTimeValue, invalidDate0,
 invalidDate1, invalidFormat].forEach(s => {
  var result;
  try {
    result = toDate(s);
    console.log(s + ' =>\n' + result.toISOString());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is a timezome format without Z at the end an accepted format? According to the ISO standard, Z is mandatory to inform that it is of UTC. Without Z, it gives GMT?